# How to allow the Guest user account to modify HKEY_CURRENT_USER in Windows XP?

Tags: windows, windows-xp, permissions, windows-registry, guest-account

As of Windows Vista, the Guest user account can add new registry keys under HKEY_CURRENT_USER.

On Windows XP, however, it's not possible. You get the error "Access denied".

Is there any permission, policy, setting or anything that can be done so that the Guest account can modify the registry as it's possible in all newer Windows versions?

---

**Follow up:**

I did more tests on a different Windows XP machine and the Guest account can indeed make modifications to HKEY_CURRENT_USER as all other Windows versions can.

I presume that the problem on the other WinXP machine is due to the antivirus (AVG) that's installed there. Although I can't be sure as disabling the antivirus' live protection did not solve the problem.

Comment: Are you sure you’re referencing the proper registry branch in your question? HKEY_CURRENT_USER is always the logged on user’s registry from their perspective, which they have full control over. As far as I know that is universal in Windows even for guest.

Comment: @Appleoddity, Apparently Windows XP is different. Right now I'm trying the command `reg add HKCU\Software\MyNewApp\confFile /ve /d "%CD%\conf.json" /f` from the Guest account and I get the message "Access Denied".

Comment: I think the problem is with your command and not the permissions. Why not use regedit and confirm if you can create these keys and values or not? The reg command has some significant differences in XP. I can’t remember what they are but I remember running in to it. I don’t see you specifying a data type, and I think you are supposed to use double percent `%%` for this type of data value, which I assume should be specified as `/t reg_expand_sz` https://www.petri.com/reg_command_in_windows_xp

Comment: By the way, I can’t find any reference to this limitation in XP. Instead, I find the opposite going back 10 years or more. A user account can’t really function without its own HKCU it can write to, I wouldn’t think.

Comment: @Appleoddity, I already tried adding the key manually using the registry, and I get an error saying that a new key could not be created. Also, the command is not the problem I already tested it on all Windows version from XP to 10. It works from the Guest account on all versions except XP.

Comment: I thought the purpose of the guest account is so that guest user cannot muck things up.